# System.Exception: 'The op is invalid` when trying to turn on the camera preview

Tags: c#, uwp

In my UWP App I can turn on the camera via a button click and can turn it off again.  But as soon as I try and turn it back on again I get the following error:

```
System.Exception: 'The op is invalid.
The op is invalid.'
```

Here is my code I am using at the moment.

```
private async void Camera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mediaCapture == null)
        {
            var cameraDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

            var backFacingDevice = cameraDevices
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.EnclosureLocation?.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

            var preferredDevice = backFacingDevice ?? cameraDevices.FirstOrDefault();
            _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

            await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(
                new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
                {
                    VideoDeviceId = preferredDevice.Id
                });

            PreviewControl.Source = _mediaCapture;

            await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
        }

        else
        {
            await _mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
        }
    }
```

I am really not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs when you repeatedly call `_mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync()`.

You can try this:

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_mediaCapture == null)
    {
        var cameraDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

        var backFacingDevice = cameraDevices
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.EnclosureLocation?.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

        var preferredDevice = backFacingDevice ?? cameraDevices.FirstOrDefault();
        _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

        await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(
            new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
            {
                VideoDeviceId = preferredDevice.Id
            });

        PreviewControl.Source = _mediaCapture;
    }

    if (_mediaCapture.CameraStreamState==Windows.Media.Devices.CameraStreamState.Streaming)
        await _mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
    else
        await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
}
```

Check if `_mediaCapture` is null when the button is clicked. If yes, initialize it first.

After this, the code that controls the `_mediaCapture` state should be performed independently, by checking `_mediaCapture.CameraStreamState` to determine the current state, and decide whether to start the preview or stop the preview.

Thanks.

Comment: Awesome explanation thank you.  It is working perfectly now!